# check valid url not returning correct result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if the mentioned url is valid url or not but its returning false even if its a valid url.

```js
function isValidUrl(urlString) {
  var urlPattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // validate protocol
        '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // validate domain name
        '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // validate OR ip (v4) address
        '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // validate port and path
        '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // validate query string
        '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', 'i'); // validate fragment locator
    return !!urlPattern.test(urlString);
}

console.log(
isValidUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18z9jEa75fDtvdzQcV_lEithQEsIKgOpcoJp3clyRYwc/edit#gid=0')
);
```

Comment: I made a snippet. You are not actually testing the passed urlString. I tried to fix that so we at least had a [mcve]

Comment: Where is this regular expression coming from? Did you create that yourself? Then you should be able to "debug" it as well, I suppose.

Comment: Here is a way to debug: https://regex101.com/r/o1IgTb/1

Comment: FYI: Using the `URL()` constructor, and catching any exceptions it might throw, can get you URL validation at practically no extra cost ... and without having to deal with your own monster regex. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-validate-urls-in-javascript/#how-to-use-the-url-constructor-to-validate-urls

Comment: This seems  invalid `(\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)` Was it supposed to be a lookahead?

Answer (score 0):

Like a comment said, use available and valid methods.

```js
try {
  // const url = new URL("nope"); // Will jump to catch(e).
  const url = new URL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18z9jEa75fDtvdzQcV_lEithQEsIKgOpcoJp3clyRYwc/edit#gid=0"); // Will continue to Valid!

  console.info("Valid!");

  // You can then do as many validation as you which.
  console.info(url);
  console.info(/https/.test(url.protocol));
  console.info(/([a-z])+\.([a-z])+/i.test(url.host));
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Not valid.");
}
```